# How do I sum an array of structures?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, operator-overloading

I am creating arrays of structures defined, when stripped to essentials for the purpose of this question, like this:-

```
Public Structure MyStruct

    Public innards As Double

    Public Shared Operator +(ByVal example1 As MyStruct, ByVal example2 As MyStruct) As MyStruct
        Dim out_struct As MyStruct
        out_struct.innards = example1.innards + example2.innards
        Return out_struct
    End Operator

End Structure
```

I then set up an array:-

```
Dim my_struct1 As MyStruct
Dim my_struct2 As MyStruct
Dim my_struct3 As MyStruct

my_struct1.innards = 1
my_struct2.innards = 2
my_struct3.innards = 3

Dim my_struct_array() As MyStruct = {my_struct1, my_struct2, my_struct3}
```

and I want to calculate the sum of the elements in the array:-

```
Dim my_total As MyStruct
my_total = my_struct_array.Sum
```

but this results in a compilation error:-

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Sum' accepts this
>   number of arguments.

Is there any way to get this to work? Some interface that I have to implement? Or do I have to resort to LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays don't have a `Sum` function but you can use LINQ; however, LINQ does not see your + operator as it only works on predefined numeric types.

```
Dim my_total As double
my_total = my_struct_array.Sum(Function(x) x.innards)
```

Your + operator works only if you work with MyStructs explicitly:

```
Dim t As MyStruct = my_struct1 + my_struct2
```

---

You could define a shared `Sum` function or an extension method. Here is a `Sum` function

```
Public Shared Function Sum(items As IEnumerable(Of MyStruct)) as MyStruct
    Dim total as double

    For Each x In items
        total += x.innards
    Next
    dim t as New MyStruct
    t.innards = total
    Return t
End Function
```

and call it like this:

```
t = MyStruct.Sum(my_struct_array)
```

---

As extension method:

```
Public Module MyExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function Sum(items As IEnumerable(Of MyStruct)) as MyStruct
        Dim total as double

        For Each x In items
            total += x.innards
        Next
        dim t as New MyStruct
        t.innards = total
        Return t
    End Function
End Module
```

Then you can do what you intended first:

```
t = my_struct_array.Sum()
```

---

One more thing: Structs should be immutable. The reason is that you always get a copy of structs, not references, when you access struct values that are in collections. If you do this:

```
my_struct_list(2).innards = 100
```

... you will not get the expected result! The list indexer returns a copy of the struct within the list, and then you change the `innards` field of this copy, but the struct in the list will not be changed!

Therefore create the struct like this:

```
Public Structure MyStruct
    Private ReadOnly m_value As Double

    Public Sub New (value as Double)
        m_value = value
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Value() As Double
        Get
            Return m_value
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared Operator +(ByVal x As MyStruct, ByVal y As MyStruct) As MyStruct
        Return New MyStruct(x.m_value + y.m_value)
    End Operator
End Structure
```

This struct is immutable. You cannot change the value once it has been initialized with `New(initialValue)`. If you want to change a value within a list, you need to do this:

```
my_struct_list(2) = New MyStruct(100)
```

This will behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a `Structure` and has underlying types there is a way to do it with a predicate that will tell the loop which property to `Sum`. `my_total` is the wrong type if you are trying to get the value of all `innards`.

```
Dim my_total = my_struct_array.Sum(Function(ms) ms.innards)
```

Comment: It produces Double, not MyStruct.

Comment: Thought that was what he was after?

Comment: Dim my_total As MyStruct.  So no.

Comment: Wow we almost wrote the exact same code, only you were faster. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534734(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) the `Sum()` method needs one argument, and also the return value is of type `Double` which means that it cannot calculate your structure. You'd have to make it calculate the values inside it instead.

Try something like this:

```
Dim my_total As MyStruct
my_total.innards = my_struct_array.Sum(Function(ms) ms.innards)
```

Answer (score 1):

In plain old :) vb.net you could try

```
Dim my_total As MyStruct
For Each item As MyStruct In my_struct_array
    my_total.innards = my_total.innards + item.innards
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a List(Of MyStructure) and sum it up using

```
ListOfMyStruct.Sum(Function(x) x.innards)
```